# jQuery UI Sortable box always has height: 0

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a ul set as a jQuery UI Sortable widget: It's height is always computed to be 0, leading to it not fitting inside its parent div. See the screenshot:

[image: Visualization of the problem]

jQuery to construct the sortable:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                // Code
            }
        });
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
```

Style of the ul:

```
    #sortable { 
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        padding: 0; 
        width: 800px; 
    }
    #sortable li {
        margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
        padding: 4px;
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 90px;
        font-size: 4em;
        background: white;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the content inside `#sortable` is all floated, which means the parent container `#sortable` doesn't expand to hold that content (the height is zero because it's essentially empty as far as the parent is concerned).  Floated content doesn't affect other content around it in the normal way, but adding an overflow forces the parent container to recognize the floated children as contained within itself and gives it a height to accommodate (as it needs to determine whether they are visible or not).

Add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to `#sortable` to make its height match the content.

However, if you want the flow of the page to be stretched to the dimensions of the sortable object, you should add a clearfix like the [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to `#sortable`. That should resolve the flow issue.

Comment: While this does resolve the issue, it introduces an unwanted UI behavior. Is it possible to rig it so that the entire height of the page is expanded? It decreases usability if the user has to scroll inside that div...

Comment: Try using the Gallagher micro clearfix hack instead - that doesn't have as many unintended consequences as `overflow` tricks often do.

Comment: The micro clearfix trick worked!! https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5yq16tdqgx0omk/Screenshot%202014-06-25%2011.29.12.png Thank you very very very much!! If you give me a paypal/dwolla acct I'll tip ya.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto` to `#sortable`.

Comment: The floated children cause the parent to collapse. Adding the overflow rule restores the expected behavior.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith see my answer for an explanation

Comment: As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) says: "If clearing floats on an element below them is not an option, another approach is to limit the block formatting context of the floats' container. We can set the overflow property on that P to hidden or auto to cause it to expand to contain them, but not allow them to drop out the bottom of it"

Comment: This works and is a suitable answer for people who want the simplicity of a single CSS attribute change. Thank you.